# Excel - INDEX MATCH NA error - sorting order

Tags: excel

I have an array formula mix index and match function aiming to search and return values based on multiple criteria.

```
=INDEX('Sheet2'!$Z$1:$AJ$16045,
       MATCH(1,('Sheet2'!$Z$1:$Z$16045=PV!$E7)*('Sheet2'!$AG$1:$AG$16045=PV!$B$1),0)
      ,10)
```

the intention is to return the value of the 10th cell(counting from column Z in sheet2) if: 
    a. Sheet 2 column Z has a value matches with E7 in the current sheet
    AND
    b. Sheet 2 column AG has a value matches with B1 in the current sheet

The issue is - Depending on what's in the cell B1, the formula sometimes only works when column Z is sorted from smallest to the largest and sometimes the formula only works when column z is sorted in the opposite order.

I understand that index/match function requires the data and match type to be consistent. But I've defined the match type to be as 0. It seems very weird to me that I need to change the sorting order for it to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't `PV!$E7` be `PV!$E$7` ?

Comment: For sn exact match, the last argument in match is ,0 so try that

Comment: @SolarMike it is ",0" currently. I've also tested both 1 and -1 with different sorting orders, still doesn't work.

Comment: @TimWilliams In the question scenario Yes. I got other cells down there that I need to drag the formula across with column E being the variables and B1 is costant. But thanks for checking.

Comment: Over what range is this formula entered?

Comment: With a Match option of `0` it shouldn't matter how your data is sorted - in my testing something similar worked fine for me.

Comment: @TimWilliams the formula is entered in E7 to E20 in the current sheet. Yes, from my understanding of match option, sorting order shouldn't matter at all when 0 is selected. Really can't figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You missed an Index() inside the match(), [ref](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria). I think it should be

```
=INDEX('Sheet2'!$Z$1:$AJ$16045,
       MATCH(1,INDEX(('Sheet2'!$Z$1:$Z$16045=PV!$E7)*('Sheet2'!$AG$1:$AG$16045=PV!$B$1),0,1),0)
      ,10)
```